# How do I write a function that takes as input an input file and an output file name, reads the input file and writes to the output file

Tags: python-3.x, file

I need to take the contents of the input file and add to each line that contains the specific input and the output should say which season that input is in.

ex. 'cs ' would output as 'cs Spring'

def aSeason(inputFile, outputFile):

```
with open(inputFile, 'r') as add:
    for lines in add:
        if lines == ['cs 101']:
            return line + ['Fall']

    if lines == ['cs 201']:
        return line + ['Spring']

with open(outputFile, 'w') as add:
```

Comment: Do you understand what `return` does?

Comment: Honestly not 100%. Can you explain in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code to read and write lines is sometimes awkward as you need to take care of invisible characters such as the newline (\n) (and in windows the carriage return(\r))

```
infile='intest.txt'
## contains: 
#cs 121
#cs 122
#cs 166
#cs 260
#cs 999

outfile='tests.txt'


with open(infile, 'r') as inf:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as outf:
        # iterate over infile lines
        for line in inf:
            # strip whitespace and newline from line read in
            sline = line.strip()

            # check if it matches some predetermined line
            if sline in ['cs 121','cs 215','cs 223','cs 260']:
                outf.writelines(sline+' Fall\n')
            elif sline in ['cs 122', 'cs 166', 'cs 224', 'cs 251', 'cs 261']:
                outf.writelines(sline + ' Spring\n')
            else:
                outf.writelines(sline+'\n') # maybe doesn't match, keep line I guess
```

To call this as a function is easy

```
def append_season(infile,outfile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as inf:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as outf:
            # iterate over infile lines
            for line in inf:
                # strip whitespace and newline from line read in
                sline = line.strip()

                # check if it matches some predetermined line
                if sline in ['cs 121','cs 215','cs 223','cs 260']:
                    outf.writelines(sline+' Fall\n')
                elif sline in ['cs 122', 'cs 166', 'cs 224', 'cs 251', 'cs 261']:
                    outf.writelines(sline + ' Spring\n')
                else:
                    outf.writelines(sline+'\n') # maybe doesn't match, keep line I guess

# call the function:
append_season(infile='intest.txt', outfile='tests.txt')
```